# How to convert Object to array of hashes with symbol keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am trying:

```
Product.first.attributes.map{|k, v| "#{k.to_sym} => #{v}"}
```

However, I receive the output as follows:

```
["id => 53", "name = blah"], ["id => 54", "name = blahblah"]
```

What I want is:

```
[{:id=>53,:name=>"blah"}, {:id=>54,:name=>"blahblah"}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're just trying to convert the `Product.first.attributes` Hash to a Hash with symbols for keys rather than strings. You can make it easy on yourself by calling the [`symbolize_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys) that Rails (ActiveSupport actually) has patched into Hash:

```
h = Product.first.attributes.symbolize_keys
```

---

When you say this:

```
"#{k.to_sym} => #{v}"
```

you're just producing a string that looks sort of like a Hash and that's not terribly useful. If you want to symbolize the keys the long way, you'd probably produce an array of arrays using:

```
...map { |k, v| [ k.to_sym, v ] }
```

and then feed that whole thing to [`Hash[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
h = Hash[Product.first.attributes.map { |k, v| [ k.to_sym, v ] }]
```

I wouldn't bother with all that noise though, just use `symbolize_keys` and move on to more interesting problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. Believe it or not I wanted to know the long way too.