# How to convert an array of Objects to array of Hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

My current array of object "sum" is:

```
[{"sum":{"key1":0,"key2":"2014","key3":0,"key4":"8","key5":0,"key6":"0","key7":0}},
 {"sum":{"key1":0,"key2":"2014","key3":0,"key4":"12","key5":0,"key6":"1","key7":0}}]
```

The target is:

```
[{"key1":0,"key2":"2014","key3":0,"key4":"8","key5":0,"key6":"0","key7":0,
 {"key1":0,"key2":"2014","key3":0,"key4":"12","key5":0,"key6":"1","key7":0}]
```

Comment: This isn't array of objects, neither valid Ruby array at all

Comment: I try to convert it to json (`render :text => a.to_json`) for you understand my data

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov That's actually valid syntax in Ruby 2.2.

Comment: @muistooshort actually, the current array is got from model `sum.find_by_sql(sql)`. I tried to get it from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` but this return a array with element is array instead of a hash

Comment: @muistooshort op mentioned that he uses Rails 2(which was removed by last editor for some unknown reason). I believe it is incompatible with Ruby 2.2 at all

Comment: So, is there a way to convert?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#flat_map`

```
array.flat_map(&:values)
# is same as :
array.flat_map { |hash| hash.values }
# or simply if you have
array.map { |hash| hash["sum"] }
```

Comment: I render array of object to json to easy understand. So, ".values" is not work, because values at here are attributes of object (hash.key1 will work)

Comment: @VuLe Your Hash inside the array.. is a valid syntax in Ruby 2.2.0... And it will work like a charm in the 2.2.0.

Comment: flat_map not work (undefined method). I tried same your last (`array.map { |hash| hash["sum"] }`), all elements are null

Comment: @VuLe It should work. Please tag the question as per the need.

Comment: I think you and others may be not understand my context clearly because of my poor English. I am sorry about that. I solved my problem already as my below answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I used `symbolize_keys` what @Muistooshort mentioned in this topic [How to convert Object to array of hashes with symbol keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669969/how-to-convert-object-to-array-of-hashes-with-symbol-keys)

So, this is code what I used:

`result = arr.map{|e| e.attributes.symbolize_keys}`